# What am I doing wrong to create this Data Frame?

Tags: r

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong in this data frame?

```
df = data.frame(Body_Parts = c("Acne",
                           "Baldness",
                           "Scar Marks",
                           "Teeth",
                           "Private Parts",
                           "Nose",
                           "Protruding Belly",
                           "Face",
                           "Birth Marks",
                           "Grey Hair",
                           "Hand/Foot Size"
                           "Eye",
                           "Lips",
                           "Muscle Size",
                           "Others"),
            percentage = c(21.2, 
                           18.0, 
                           10.4, 
                           9.4, 
                           5.8, 
                           5.4, 
                           5.3, 
                           4.9, 
                           3.7, 
                           2.2, 
                           2.1, 
                           1.7, 
                           1.7,
                           1.3,
                           7.1))
```

I am continuously getting an error with this code. 
This is the error output
[image]

Comment: You're missing a comma between `"Hand/Foot Size"` and `"Eye"`

Comment: Thanks, dear..You just saved me from going to the mental asylum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the , after "Hand/Foot Size"